# Why does the min() CSS function leave empty space in a container?

Tags: html, css

I'm running into a problem with the CSS `min()` function.

Here are a few code snippets to demonstrate my issue (pay attention to the `<p>` element's styling):

### Snippet 1 (`<p>` `width: 100%`):

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  /* max-width: min(100px, 100%); */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

### Snippet 2 (`<p>` `width: 100px`):

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  max-width: 100px;
  /* max-width: min(100px, 100%); */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

### Snippet 3 (`<p>` `width: min(100px, 100%)`):

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  max-width: min(100px, 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

My understanding of the CSS `min()` function is that it should resolve to whatever the most negative value contained within it's parentheses is. In the context of snippet 3, I would expect the visual output to be the same as snippet 2. However, the actual output of snippet 3 seems to render the `<p>` element with the width of 100px but the containing `<div>` element seems to view the `<p>` element with the 100% width of snippet 2.

My question is - what exactly is the cause of the empty space in snippet 3, and more to the point, how do I resolve it while keeping the CSS `min()` function?

Any help would be really appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min()` is working fine but the issue is elsewhere and is related to `fit-content`. Don't forget that you are using "max-wdith" and you are setting the background color on the div.

Check the below:

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  max-width: min(100px, 100%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

The `p` element is having a width equal to `100px` which confirms that `min()` is working fine.

Now you need to understand how `fit-content` works and how percentage interact with it.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#cyclic-percentage-contribution)

> Sometimes the size of a percentage-sized box’s containing block depends on the intrinsic size contribution of the box itself, creating a cyclic dependency. ..

Then you have a very long detailed explanation not easy to grasp but I will use easy words to explain in.

You are using `max-width: min(100px, 100%)` so you have a percentage sizing. In order to resolve this we need a reference which is the parent width but the latter is define as `fit-content` meaning that it also depend on the child width. In such case, the browser will first ignore the percentage value to define the parent width.

We get this:

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  /*max-width: min(100px, 100%);*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

Now we have the width of the parent and **this one will not more change**. Then we calculate the percentage based on that width to get the result you know:

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  /*max-width: min(100px, 100%);*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="max-width: min(100px, 100%)">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

In other words, if you are using percentage in `max-width`, the `fit-content` will ignore it. For this reason the 1st and 3rd snippet will give you the same result.

You will also get the same result if you consider `width` as well.

Here are more examples to show you different cases of percentage where the `fit-content` will behave the same:

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="max-width: min(100px, 100%)">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="max-width: min(100px, 10%)">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="width: 50%">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="width: min(100px, 10%)">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="width: 200%">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p style="width: max(100px, 10%)">
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

Whatever the combination of property/values you will use, if percentage is used, the `fit-content` will always give the same result. It will ignore any property using percentage values to calculate the width of the element.

Comment: Sorry for delay in acknowledging this but a very detailed and clear answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `div { width: fit-content; }`. `width: 100%` means 100% of the parents width. As the parent (div)  however is specifically set to only be as wide as the content, the width: 100% does nto work anymore. Because then it is now 100% of undefined which is also undefined.

```css
div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

p {
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  max-width: min(100px, 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is some example text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The `width: fit-content` is just to create a more simplified scenario to better understand the problem, so do not fixate on that, as this issue occurs in other scenarios as well. Besides that point, with the '<div>' element being styled to fit it's contents, why hasn't it shrunk to fit it's contents in snippet 3?

Comment: then you need to be more explicit. The issue does not occure when you remove it in my snippet.

Comment: Also, snippet 1 includes `max-width: 100%`, which renders without any empty-space. So I don't think your logic checks out for determining the issue here.

Comment: it does not for me. Its only as wide as the text is.

Comment: so why does snippet 3 render the `div` element with empty space then?

Comment: because you should use `minmax` instead of `min`

Comment: Isn't that used in CSS grids? So not applicable here?